# Migrate Hive tables to redshift

Tags: hive, amazon-redshift, data-migration

Let me explain a bit the scenario:
I have hundreds of hive tables stored on S3 (ORC, Parquet), so just to be clear no HDFS.
Now, I am interested in migrating some of them to Redshift to run some performance tests.
I know that redshift does not support ORC, Parquet so I need to create some CSV/JSON to be able to use the COPY command.
I am thinking of using Hive itself to create temporary CSV tables and then migrate to Redshift. I was also thinking of using Spark to move this data.
Anyone with experience in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way for migrating the data into redshift. So first of all you need to load that parquet or orc into Spark (pyspark, java or scala)  then you can directly insert those data into redshift using databricks package. Below is the link for databricks package which includes some examples.

https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift

Comment: I tried this option, the redshift databricks package works very well

Answer (score 5):

You can set up Redshift Spectrum so that your S3 tables look like Redshift tables, you can then query the data directly or bring it in to internal Redshift tables.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-tables.html

ORC and Parquet are fully supported.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-data-files.html